# Using RGBA5555 on cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can i use the RGBA5555 pixel format on cocos2d?

I define my pixel formats like this:

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
```

and i've found these:

```
// Available textures 
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 - 32-bit texture with Alpha channel
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB565 - 16-bit texture without Alpha channel
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_A8 - 8-bit textures used as masks
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_I8 - 8-bit intensity texture
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_AI88 - 16-bit textures used as masks
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444 - 16-bit textures: RGBA4444
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGB5A1 - 16-bit textures: RGB5A1
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_PVRTC4 - 4-bit PVRTC-compressed texture: PVRTC4
// kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_PVRTC2 - 2-bit PVRTC-compressed texture: PVRTC2
```

but i can't seem to find the RGBA5555. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no RGBA5555 format. That would amount to 4 times 5 Bits = 20 Bits. Such a texture format doesn't exist anywhere.

If you're looking for RGB5551, meaning 5 Bits for each RGB color and 1 Bit for alpha, then you're looking for the RGB5A1 format.

Comment: hi sorry for the late answer... i was using texture packer for my sprites and it was one of the formats it supported... why?